# Json_Decode not decoding into object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{&quot;order_product_id&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;design_order&quot;:[&quot;design_number_1&quot;],&quot;design_number_1&quot;:{&quot;sort_order&quot;:[&quot;Design Number&quot;],&quot;Design Number&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}}
```

I am trying to turn it into a PHP object like this:

```
$obj = json_decode($data,true);
```

But $obj is alway null. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT

This is my ajax request.

```
response = JSON.stringify(response);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",           
            url: "<?php echo $submit_url; ?>",
            data: { 'data' :response},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);  
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

- You have to decode the HTML first
- You have to *not* specify `true` as the second argument (that means "create an associative array instead of an object)

Such:

```
<?php
$data = "{&quot;order_product_id&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;design_order&quot;:[&quot;design_number_1&quot;],&quot;design_number_1&quot;:{&quot;sort_order&quot;:[&quot;Design Number&quot;],&quot;Design Number&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}}";
$data = htmlspecialchars_decode($data);
$obj = json_decode($data);
print_r($obj);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [order_product_id] => 6
    [design_order] => Array
        (
            [0] => design_number_1
        )

    [design_number_1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sort_order] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Design Number
                )

            [Design Number] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: The response literally has `&quot;`?

Comment: @user3167249 — JSON uses `"` to delimit strings. You can't use the HTML `&quot;`.

Comment: Why not `html_entity_decode()`? Is there a specific reason as to why you chose `htmlspecialchars_decode`?

Comment: is that because I am sending it through post? This is the variable value before I submit it to php: {"order_product_id":"6","design_order":["design_number_1"],"design_number_1":{"sort_order":["Design Number"],"Design Number":"1"}}

Comment: @user3167249 — If that is what you are sending, then you shouldn't get the data in the format you claim you do in the question.

Comment: @AmalMurali — Cmd+Underscore.

Comment: I have made an edit to show how I submit the data. No &quot; in response on javascript side

Comment: The htmlspecialchars_decode did work, but can anyone tell me why it is being encoded with htmlspecialchars in the first place?